# php jru and Ireport

Tags: php, jasper-reports

Im using php jru to connect to ireport, using this code:

```
<?php require_once('http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc'); 
require_once("PHPJRU/php-jru.php");

$jru = new PJRU();
$Reporte = 'C://wamp//www//test.jasper';
$SalidaReporte = 'C://wamp//www//';
$Conexion = new JdbcConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/trafico","root","root");

$Parametro=new java('java.util.HashMap');

$jru->runReportToPdfFile($Reporte,$SalidaReporte,$Parametro,$Conexion->getConnection());

?>
```

It gets the following error

```
java stack trace: java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[c:JasperRunManager]]->runReportToPdfFile((o:String)[o:String], (o:String)[o:String], (i:Map)[o:HashMap], (i:Connection)[o:Connection]). Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException VM: 1.7.0_79@http://java.oracle.com/
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2036)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile(JasperRunManager.java:122)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.Invoke(JavaBridge.java:1044)
at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:417)
at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
at php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145)
at php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
... 25 more
```

The problem is that my report doesn´t need any parameter. What should I pass in that argument?

Comment: Have you tried `NULL`? I've never worked with JRU... Is there any documentation/code comments?

Comment: I've already tried NULL, but it doesn't work, I update my question!